# To what extent can a spouse assist in a legal case?

Tags: canada, legal-representation

My spouse has been named in a statement of offence by a municipal court. If found guilty, the charge would result in a fine that would ultimately affect us both. I was, in fact, witness to the event (she wasn't even there) but due to certain registration paperwork she was the person named in the offence.

I am not a lawyer, but I do have a better grasp of the relevant law than she does, and I'm better at expressing myself in stressful situations. To what extent can I aid in the case? Obviously we'll be discussing things in private, at what point would it become "legal advice"? If we are talking to certain parties (prosecution, judge, witnesses, etc.) can I do any of the talking? (obviously she would be present and consenting).

The costs involved don't warrant hiring a lawyer, and we can't afford one even if we wanted to.

Comment: When you talk to people tell them you are her husband and not an attorney.

Comment: This asks what the lae permits. It does not ask for specific legal advice, nd should not be closed on that basis.